# Xamarin MVVM working with files

Tags: c#, file, mvvm, xamarin

I'm developing app for iOS and Android using Xamarin and MVVM. App should upload\download files to\from server. In details, there is a button on Android, clickin on it Android file picker opens and I'm getting file. The same in iOS. The issue is that I'm trying to send file into viewmodel as Stream, but in Android it is as `Android.Runtime.InputStreamInvoker` and in iOS is as `NSData`. Is there any universal way for sending file's stream into viewmodel or anything casting? And casting to Stream doesn't work, when I send it is not viewmodel, I can't get any info from stream. Maybe anybody had such issue.

As example, on Android receiving file:

```
public override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent)
{
    base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
    if (resultCode == (int)Result.Ok)
    {
        var returnUri = intent.Data;
        var mimeType = _baseActivity.ContentResolver.GetType(returnUri);
        var returnCursor =
                _baseActivity.ContentResolver.Query(returnUri, null, null, null, null);
        int nameIndex = returnCursor.GetColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DisplayName);
        int sizeIndex = returnCursor.GetColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.Size);
        returnCursor.MoveToFirst();
        var name = returnCursor.GetString(nameIndex);
        var size = returnCursor.GetLong(sizeIndex);

        var inputStream = (Android.Runtime.InputStreamInvoker) _baseActivity.ContentResolver.OpenInputStream(returnUri);
        var count = inputStream.BaseInputStream.Available();

        //then I want to send inputStrea here what to do next??
    }
}
```

I know that I can read whole file and copy it into for example `MemoryStream` and send, but it is very slow and not good, I'm searching for a method without making copies.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes in cases like this I will just type the property as `System.Object`. The binding system uses reflection to access the property at runtime, so it doesn't really matter what concrete type your property is using.

This assumes that whatever is being wired up to your viewmodel will be OK with getting a NSData (when on iOS) or the Android equivalent when on that platform.